# Jobs finishing successfully even though IOException occurs

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, ioexception

I receive various IOException on my master node when running the GridMix and I wonder if this is something I should be really concerned about or is it something transient as my jobs are finishing successfully:

```
IOException: Bad connect ack with firstBadLink: \
java.io.IOException: Bad response ERROR for block BP-49483579-10.0.1.190-1449960324681:blk_1073746606_5783 from datanode 10.0.1.192:50010
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer$ResponseProcessor.run(DFSOutputStream.java:819)
```

Comment: If it's working, I'd ignore it. But be careful not to ignore similar exceptions that might cause issues later on.

Comment: Are these due to transient errors in networks or data nodes or are they rather permanent errors and should I try to fix them preferably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot be sure until I understand your complete setup but high possibility is that these exceptions are occurring while appending to pipeline setup, in terms of code you can say that `stage == BlockConstructionStage.PIPELINE_SETUP_APPEND`.

In any case since your jobs are getting successfully finished you need not to worry, and why it is getting successfully finished is **because** when trying to open a DataOutputStream to a DataNode pipeline and some exception occurs then it keeps on trying until a pipeline is setup.

The exception occurs from [`org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/0.23.1/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DFSOutputStream.java), and below are important code snippets for your understanding.

```
 private boolean createBlockOutputStream(DatanodeInfo[] nodes, long newGS, boolean recoveryFlag) {
    //Code..
    if (pipelineStatus != SUCCESS) {
      if (pipelineStatus == Status.ERROR_ACCESS_TOKEN) {
        throw new InvalidBlockTokenException(
            "Got access token error for connect ack with firstBadLink as "
                + firstBadLink);
      } else {
        throw new IOException("Bad connect ack with firstBadLink as "
            + firstBadLink);
      }
    }
    //Code..
}
```

Now, `createBlockOutputStream` is called from `setupPipelineForAppendOrRecovery`, and as the code comment for this method mentions - "It keeps on trying until a pipeline is setup".

```
/**
 * Open a DataOutputStream to a DataNode pipeline so that 
 * it can be written to.
 * This happens when a file is appended or data streaming fails
 * It keeps on trying until a pipeline is setup
 */
private boolean setupPipelineForAppendOrRecovery() throws IOException {
    //Code..
    while (!success && !streamerClosed && dfsClient.clientRunning) {
        //Code..
        success = createBlockOutputStream(nodes, newGS, isRecovery);
    }
    //Code..
}
```

And if you will go through the complete `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream` code you will understand that pipeline setup trial will keep on going until a pipeline is created for append or fresh use.

If you want to handle it then you can try to adjust `dfs.datanode.max.xcievers` property from `hdfs-site.xml`, maximum people have reported solution from the same. Please note that you need to restart your hadoop services after you set the property.

```
<property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.max.xcievers</name>
        <value>8192</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Are these due to transient errors in networks or data nodes or are they rather permanent errors and should I try to fix them preferably?

Comment: so I am using an open-source code that doesn't have that property `dfs.datanode.max.xcievers` in `hdfs-site.xml` should I add it?

Comment: It could be because of network or could be because of maximum number of nodes availability. Try adding and property and also setting `dfs.datanode.max.transfer.threads` which is mentioned in this post - https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/X64MxNhkbiI .. This post says they got helped with these but problem came back again, so I would say that high possibility is network issue .. In any case I think you will not have functional impact because of hadoop re-tries mechanism, so you should be good ..

Answer (score 0):

Ignore it?

```
try {
  ...
} catch (IOException iox) {
  //***NOP***
}
```

Comment: OP has already said that her jobs are getting completed but she wants to know if she should be concerned about it.

Comment: I think she should.